# JBoss switchyard exception - How to stop printing long exception message in log

Tags: jboss, apache-camel, switchyard

I have JBoss switchyard application deployed in JBoss EAP 6.1. Whenever there is any exception, lots of error messages are flooded in log. I need only first few lines of the message but not the rest. Because we know the root cause of the exception looking at the first few lines only. Rest of the lines are really useless. Those are detailed stacktrace. How to stop these message from appearing? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Log snippet:

```
04-05-2016 20:08:36,360 ERROR (org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler) [Camel (camel-38) thread #67 - file:///integrations/hybris-esb/in/i215/pending] Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-ESBS
RVPRDEU01-goep-hm-com-44700-1461855065835-37-23110 on ExchangeId: ID-ESBSRVPRDEU01-goep-hm-com-44700-1461855065835-37-23111). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.switchyard.HandlerExcept
ion: org.switchyard.HandlerException: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot connect to sftp://username@11.11.11.11:4022: org.switchyard.HandlerException: org.sw
itchyard.HandlerException: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot connect to sftp://username@11.11.11.11:4022
        at org.switchyard.component.camel.SwitchYardConsumer.handleMessage(SwitchYardConsumer.java:115) [switchyard-component-camel-switchyard-1.1.1-p9-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1-p9-redhat-1]
        at org.switchyard.bus.camel.processors.ProviderProcessor.process(ProviderProcessor.java:29) [switchyard-bus-camel-1.1.1-p9-redhat-1-BZ-1286688.jar:1.1.1-p9-redhat-1-BZ-1286688]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:91) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.switchyard.bus.camel.audit.FaultProcessor.process(FaultProcessor.java:46) [switchyard-bus-camel-1.1.1-p9-redhat-1-BZ-1286688.jar:1.1.1-p9-redhat-1-BZ-1286688]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.fabric.FabricTraceProcessor.process(FabricTraceProcessor.java:81) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:46) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:308) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:117) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.TryProcessor.process(TryProcessor.java:104) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.TryProcessor.process(TryProcessor.java:78) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:73) [camel-core-2.10.0.redhat-60065.jar:2.10.0.redhat-60065]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn of logging stacktraces and much more by configuring the default error handler.

Some information on the Camel website: http://camel.apache.org/dead-letter-channel.html

Comment: I have a file producer and am using onException. Using handled(true) stops printing long error msg in log but moveFailed(switchyard provides this feature in GUI itself) doesn't move the original file to expected folder. I need something where unnecessary logs can be avoided and movefailed will work.